# Execute dynamic query with postgresql-simple

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I need to execute arbitrary SQL commands composed as string via Haskell or even loaded from files.

The postgresql-simple library provides `execute_` and `exec` for executing SQL commands. The problem with `execute_` is that it needs a `Query` as parameter. I do understand the intention behind that but I need to execute arbitrary queries. The `exec` function can be called without a `Query` but is undocumented and fails silently without exception on error.

How can I convert a `String` to a `Query`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Query` is an instance of `IsString`, so you can use `Data.String.fromString` to convert arbitrary string to `Query`.